# Fiware-quantumleap has issues getting and changing the updated values

Tags: fiware

The values sent to the Fiware IoT-agent-json are being successfully updated in CB. But, quantumleap 0.7.6 won't get them anymore (It was working just fine and cratedb was storing the recieved data normally)..the sanity check shows that It's healthy..I think something is going wrong with the DB. The logs shows something like this..

```
ERROR:app:Exception on /v2/notify [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 48, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/uri_parsing.py", line 144, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 184, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 384, in wrapper
    return function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return function(**kwargs)
  File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/reporter/reporter.py", line 189, in notify
    trans.insert(payload, fiware_s, fiware_sp)
  File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/translators/sql_translator.py", line 179, in insert
    res = self._insert_entities_of_type(et,
  File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/translators/sql_translator.py", line 273, in _insert_entities_of_type
    self._update_metadata_table(table_name, original_attrs)
  File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/translators/sql_translator.py", line 414, in _update_metadata_table
    self._store_medatata(table_name, persisted_metadata)
  File "/src/ngsi-timeseries-api/src/translators/crate.py", line 157, in _store_medatata
    self.cursor.execute(stmt, (table_name, persisted_metadata))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crate/client/cursor.py", line 53, in execute
    self._result = self.connection.client.sql(sql, parameters,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 331, in sql
    content = self._json_request('POST', self.path, data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 458, in _json_request
    _raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crate/client/http.py", line 187, in _raise_for_status
    raise ProgrammingError(error.get('message', ''),
crate.client.exceptions.ProgrammingError: SQLActionException[InvalidColumnNameException: "5.9" contains a dot]
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://crate-db:4200 "POST /_sql?error_trace=true HTTP/1.1" 400 6596
DEBUG:connexion.apis.abstract:Getting data and status code
DEBUG:connexion.apis.abstract:Prepared body and status code (500)
DEBUG:connexion.apis.abstract:Getting data and status code
DEBUG:connexion.apis.abstract:Got framework response
```

The orion logs shows the following:

```
logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: POST /v2/entities/station:2/attrs?type=WeatherObserved, request payload (338 bytes): {"temperature":{"type":"Integer","value":19,"metadata":{"TimeInstant":{"type":"DateTime","value":"2021-03-08T10:23:34.295Z"}}},"location":{"type":"geo:point","value":"36.59389,10.30212","metadata":{"TimeInstant":{"type":"DateTime","value":"2021-03-08T10:23:34.295Z"}}},"TimeInstant":{"type":"DateTime","value":"2021-03-08T10:23:34.295Z"}}, response code: 204
time=2021-03-08T10:23:34.327Z | lvl=WARN | corr=56645b84-7ff8-11eb-b242-0242ac120006; cbnotif=1 | trans=1615196386-384-00000000093 | from=172.18.0.8 | srv=smartwater | subsrv=/weatherstation | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[583]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification response NOT OK, http code: 500
time=2021-03-08T10:23:34.327Z | lvl=INFO | corr=56645b84-7ff8-11eb-b242-0242ac120006; cbnotif=1 | trans=1615196386-384-00000000093 | from=172.18.0.8 | srv=smartwater | subsrv=/weatherstation | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[63]:logInfoNotification | msg=Notif delivered (subId: 601aabeb96fce3b0209b8aa8): POST quantumleap:8668/v2/notify, response code: 500
time=2021-03-08T10:23:34.327Z | lvl=WARN | corr=56645b84-7ff8-11eb-b242-0242ac120006; cbnotif=2 | trans=1615196386-384-00000000094 | from=172.18.0.8 | srv=smartwater | subsrv=/weatherstation | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[583]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification response NOT OK, http code: 500
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly an attribute name as reported by the message:
`InvalidColumnNameException: "5.9" contains a dot`

Try using `5_9` as attribute name.